# Redis and SSE Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, server-sent-events

I am following the Rails 4 SSE Action controller live and Redis pub/sub on Railscast

http://railscasts.com/episodes/401-actioncontroller-live

But, my browser is loading for ever after implementing this. Seems the req-res cycle is bocked at Redis subscription code block.

How can I get this working. Please help

Comment: Just a critique on your question - providing code would be more useful for others to assist you. Also, that railscast is subscription-only so only those who have paid would know what is in that 'cast.

Answer (score 2):

The redis.subscribe method blocks, awaiting a message on the queue. Have you tried adding a message on the queue, and seeing if your supplied block is called?

Also, try using a command line tool such as curl so you can see your events coming back:

```
curl -v https://your.webserver.com/events
```